# Which are the advantages/disadvantages of \includestandalone?

Tags: graphics, standalone

I've just found out that the command

```
\includestandalone[<options>]{<file>}
```

exists.

Which are its advantages/disadvantages with respect to the `\includegraphics{<file>}` of the output image?

For example, if I have `myfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=red]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with `\includestandalone` I have to put in the preamble of the main file all the packages present in the standalone preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\includestandalone{myfile}
\end{document}
```

whereas if I only include the output, of course, I don't need them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{myfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at the _package_ code of `standalone` it looks like it checks the modification time of the `.tex` file and if it is newer than that of the `.pdf` file then it starts a standalone job to update the `.pdf` file. It looks like the externalisation thing in Ti*k*Z. So I'd say that an advantage is that it updates the file if necessary. There's probably much more than that, but this is what I saw by quickly looking into the code.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, you could also write an answer if you like.

Comment: As I understand it it is in effect a variation of the principles of subfiles. That is the subfiles are potentially compilable standalone OR can be included in which case they are not only physically cropped area but also tex is cropped from begin{document} to end{document} thus why it needs the preambles to be included for those imported commands

Comment: @KJO Thanks, you could write an answer, too, if you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one advantage, I do not claim it is the most important one. It goes in the same direction as the comments by Phelype and KJO, and is essentially copied from [here](https://texwelt.de/wissen/antwort_link/23097/). Consider this subfile `sub.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\ifstandalone
\tikzset{my style/.style={line width=3pt}}
\fi
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[->,my style] (0,1cm)--++(4,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you compile it, you get

[image]

However, you can also embed *and modify* it in a main document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\tikzset{my style/.style={line width=15pt}}
\includestandalone[mode=tex]{sub}
\caption{Version 1.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\tikzset{my style/.style={red, line width=7pt}}
\includestandalone[mode=tex]{sub}\caption{Version 2.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, you can manipulate it from outside which you can't if you use `\includegraphics`.

Of course, you can generalize this example in many ways. Within Ti*k*Z, you can play with `every node` and the like, but this discussion is certainly restricted to Ti*k*Z. With

```
\ifstandalone
<some defintions>
\fi
```

you can create many examples where you define a macro in one way if it is compiled as standalone and in other ways depending on which document embeds the stuff. I *started* using these things for figures that get embedded in either notes or beamer presentations, but do not have used them extensively. So far these tricks work great.

Comment: +1, interesting!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I think Marmot has it covered but I was playing with \begin{document} \input{carlatex} \scalebox{2}{\input{Marmot}} Hats off to you M'am \end{document} :-} edit PS my Marmot was a variation on Issue#1 in GitHub issues with a 40^ jaunty hat e.g. \begin{tikzpicture}
 \marmot
 \thing[hat,xshift=1.2cm,yshift=-0.9cm,rotate=40]